# SQL query where clause filter based on another column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, select

Below query I am trying to filter status id =7 records for team_id>1
But want to include records with status_id=7 for team_id=1.How can we write the query.

```
 SELECT MAX(created_date) AS maxtime,
        TEAM_ID,
        ticket_id 
 FROM ri_ticket_status_history  
 WHERE status_id<>7    
 GROUP BY TEAM_ID,ticket_id
```

Comment: The description is different from your query. I can not see any team in where statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of `and` and `or` logical operators should do it:

```
SELECT   MAX(created_date) AS maxtime ,team_id, ticket_id 
FROM     ri_ticket_status_history 
WHERE    (status_id <> 7 AND team_id > 1) OR team_id = 1
GROUP BY team_id, ticket_id
```

Comment: It would be better: status_id<>7 AND team_id >= 1

Comment: @RenatoReyes - nope, that will exclude rows with status_id=7 and team_id=1.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select max(created_date) as maxtime ,TEAM_ID,ticket_id 
from  ri_ticket_status_history 
where status_id<>7  or  (status_id=7 and team_id=1)
group by TEAM_ID,ticket_id
```

Answer (score 1):

> brace location can change the result set.

```
select max(created_date) as maxtime ,TEAM_ID,ticket_id 
from  ri_ticket_status_history 
where ( status_id<>7  or  (status_id=7 and team_id=1))
group by TEAM_ID,ticket_id
```